# No idea how to finalize the function of selecting data from Data Frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix

I am developing a function that extracts data from the dataframe based on the interaction matrix between factor levels. The input of the function is the Dataframe, the Matrix of interaction between factor levels and the number of the column containing factor data. The interaction matrix consists of zeros and ones and is symmetric about the main diagonal. The names of columns and rows in the matrix are factor levels. Please help the respected community with finalization of the function.

Matrix of interaction between factor levels:

```
structure(c(1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1), dim = c(5L, 5L), dimnames = list(c("15", 
"20", "30", "40", "50"), c("15", "20", "30", "40", "50")))
```

Dataframe view:

```
structure(list(NumObr = structure(1:6, levels =     c("1",     "2", "3", 
"4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14",     "15", 
"16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", "24", "25",     "26", 
"27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "33", "34", "35", "36",     "37", 
"38", "39", "40", "41", "42", "43", "44", "45", "46", "47",     "48", 
"49", "50", "51", "52", "53", "54", "55", "56", "57", "58",     "59", 
"60", "61", "62", "63", "64", "65", "66", "67", "68", "69",     "70", 
"71", "72", "73", "74", "75", "76", "77", "78", "79", "80",     "81", 
"82", "83", "84", "85", "86", "87", "88", "89", "90", "91",     "92", 
"93", "94", "95", "96", "97", "98", "99", "100", "101",     "102", 
"103", "104", "105", "106", "107", "108", "109", "110",     "111", 
"112", "113", "114", "115", "116", "117", "118", "119",     "120", 
"121", "122", "123", "124", "125", "126", "127", "128",     "129", 
"130", "131", "132", "133", "134", "135", "136", "137",     "138", 
"139", "140", "141", "142", "143", "144", "145", "146",     "147", 
"148", "149", "150", "151", "152", "153", "154", "155",     "156", 
"157", "158", "159", "160", "161", "162", "163", "164",     "165", 
"166", "167", "168", "169", "170", "171", "172", "173",     "174", 
"175", "176", "177", "178", "179", "180", "181", "182",     "183", 
"184", "185", "186", "187", "188", "189", "190", "191",     "192", 
"193", "194", "195", "196", "197", "198", "199", "200",     "201", 
"202", "203", "204", "205", "206", "207", "208", "209",     "210", 
"211", "212", "213", "214", "215"), class = "factor"),     RastvPoly = c(20L, 
20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L), ModUpr = c(207.9995904,     213.9623982, 
202.6860729, 202.1958851, 195.1508638, 204.9938721), ForsMax     = c(1517.935303, 
1529.544189, 1502.401001, 1495.139526, 1521.255737,     1498.248901
), PredProch = c(3415.354431, 3441.474426, 3380.402252,     3364.063934, 
3422.825409, 3371.060028), dLmax = c(1.440741164,     1.459018333, 
1.44097243, 1.435998338, 1.492951597, 1.435195548), LenObr =     c(236L, 
236L, 236L, 236L, 236L, 236L), Weight = c(261L, 263L, 267L,     249L, 
264L, 266L), ConcVol = c(72.33716475, 71.78707224,     70.71161049, 
75.82329317, 71.51515152, 70.97744361), RastvPolyF =     structure(c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), levels = c("15", "20", "30", "40",     "50"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
6L), class = "data.frame")
```

```
  numFactor <- function(dataAnaliz){
  nameCol <- names(dataAnaliz)
  numName <- length(nameCol)
  numF <- c()
  for (i in seq(1,numName,1)) {
    if(class(dataAnaliz[,i])=="factor"){
      numF <- c(numF,i)
    }else{
      next
    }
  }
  return(numF)
}
numPredictor <- function(dataAnaliz){
  nameCol <- names(dataAnaliz)
  numName <- length(nameCol)
  numP <- c()
  for (i in seq(1,numName,1)) {
    if(class(dataAnaliz[,i])=="numeric"){
      numP <- c(numP,i)
    }else{
      next
    }
  }
  return(numP)
}

netFactor <- function(dataAnaliz, numF, numP, alpha){
  levFactor <- levels(dataAnaliz[,numF])
  pMatrix<-matrix(rep(0,length(levFactor)^2),ncol = length(levFactor),nrow = length(levFactor))
  colnames(pMatrix) <- levFactor
  rownames(pMatrix) <- levFactor
  k<-1
  for (i in levFactor) {
    m<-1
    for (j in levFactor) {
      test<- t.test(dataAnaliz[dataAnaliz[,numF]==i, numP],dataAnaliz[dataAnaliz[,numF]==j, numP], correct=FALSE)$p.value
      test <- p.adjust(test, method = "bonferroni",n=length(levFactor))
      if(test>=alpha){
        pMatrix[j,i]<-1
      }else{
        pMatrix[j,i]<-0
      }
      m<-m+1
    }
    k<-k+1
  }
  return(pMatrix)
}

dataSelect <-function(dataAnaliz,netF, numF){
    conFrame <- data.frame(as.table(netF))
    conFrameOne<-conFrame[(conFrame$Freq==1)&(conFrame$Var1!=conFrame$Var2),]
    varCol1 <- conFrameOne$Var1
    varCol2 <- conFrameOne$Var2
    vec<- c()
    for (i in varCol2) {
      vec_1 <-c()
      for (j in varCol1) {
        if((length(conFrameOne[conFrameOne$Var1==j&conFrameOne$Var2==i,]$Freq)!=0)&(i!=j)){
          vec_1 <- c(vec_1,i,j)
        }else{
          vec_1 <- c(vec_1,"|","|")
        }
      }
      vec<-rbind(vec,vec_1)
    }
    
    newVec <- c()
    numRow<- nrow(vec)
    for (i in seq(1,numRow-1,1)) {
      if(!identical(vec[i+1,], vec[i,])){
        newVec<-rbind(newVec,vec[i+1,])
      }
    }
    
    print(newVec)
    conFrameZero <- conFrame[conFrame$Freq==0,]
    levCFZ <- levels(conFrameZero$Var1)
    for ( i in levCFZ) {
      if(length(conFrameZero[conFrameZero$Var2==i,]$Var2)==(length(levCFZ)-1)){
        #print(dataAnaliz[dataAnaliz[,numF]==i,])
      }
    }
    
  }
  print(numP<-numPredictor(newDataMISIS))
  print(nf<-numFactor(newDataMISIS))
  print(netF<-netFactor(newDataMISIS,numF = nf[2], numP[4], 0.05))
  
  dataSelect(newDataMISIS,netF,nf[2])
```

Thanks in advance to all those who responded. Best regards!

Tried most of the standard options, but it fails to preserve the structure of the interaction between factor levels in the selected data.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Please provide some test data, and the expected output based on that input.  This will make your question reproducible.  [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) will help you construct a *minimal reproducible example*.

Comment: Added data snapshots, didn't quite figure out how to add a csv file

Comment: Please don't upload code, error messages, results or data as images for [these reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) - and [these](https://xkcd.com/2116/). At the moment, you're asking us to spend time retyping your data before evn starting to answer your question.  Is that reasonable?  You don't need to add as  CSV file.  Just `dput()` the object you create from the contents of the CSV file.  Use `dput(head())` if the file is large.

Comment: Took your advice, but not sure if it would be informative. In any case, I would be grateful for your help

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to do, having expected output (given this sample data) would be helpful. Additionally, without knowing what `numPredictor`, `numFactor`, or `netFactor` are doing, we can't be certain what your called arguments are. Lastly, inside your function your `vec_1` is formed either by `c(vec_1, i, j)`, which will append the `factor`s to the vector, or `c(vec_1, "|", "|")` which are appending `character`. Unfortunately, the `factor`s here are converted to strings of the integer indices from the levels, so your data types are not consistent.

Comment: I've added the code for the missing functions. Based on the test of statistically significant differences, a matrix of relatedness of levels in a factor is formed. further I try to divide the data according to this matrix.